# Why does spring-ws not detect a spring configuration file if declared in the root context.

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-ws

I am having a weird problem. I have a my-spring.xml file i would like to add to application but for some reason i can only get it to be detected if it is in the root context.

The following does not detect the my-spring.xml declared in the root context.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" 
         version="2.4">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/my-datasources.xml
        /WEB-INF/my-spring.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/webservice-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wsdl</extension>
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xsd</extension>
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

If i change it to this then it works (Note the difference in the location of my-spring.xml).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" 
         version="2.4">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/my-datasources.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/webservice-config.xml</param-value>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/my-spring.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wsdl</extension>
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xsd</extension>
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I cant really see what i am doing wrong. If i understood the way this works, when declared on the root context (as in the first example) it should be accessed by any resource throught the application. This does not seem to be the case in this example as i cant access the properties defined in the my-spring.xml file from the Controller/Endpoint class.

Comment: Does the first config work if you change the first context-param to ```<context-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>classpath*:WEB-INF/my-*.xml</param-value></context-param>```?

Comment: I was going to suggest the same. +1

Comment: Just tried that but still no difference. It also complained of not finding the transaction-manager which was in the my-datasources file meaning it could not load any of the files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need commas to separate multiple `contextConfigLocation` files. Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725413/116509

Edit: Try removing the preceding `/` e.g. `WEB-INF/my-datasources.xml` rather than `/WEB-INF/my-datasources.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```xml
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/my-datasources.xml
            classpath:/my-spring.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>
```

But you must have these 2 files in classpath

Comment: Yes this is what i am thinking. Is /WEB-INF considered to be in the classpath or do they have to be in /WEB-INF/classes ?

Comment: You need in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib--> inside any .jar file

Comment: Thanks - This will probably work but i need to understand why using WEB-INF/my-spring.xml does not work when it is supposed to work.

Comment: contextConfigLocation tries to find the file in specified path, but path which we provide, is a relative path and not the absolute path. So it is always better to have such configuration files in the classpath.